# Splitting multiple noncontiguous polylines into multiple files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line

I have multiple polyline shapefiles that are non-contiguous, that is to say that each shapefile contains polylines that have breaks in them. I am looking to split each of these polyline segments into its own shapefile. Furthermore, I need to do this for several hundred shapefiles, so I am wondering if there is a code I can write in python, or else a function that exists in ArcGIS itself to do this quickly for all of the shapefiles.

Comment: Are you wanting to separate the polylines into separate Shapefiles or actually break up the polylines into segments? If it is the first option then a simple model with a feature iterator would achieve this.

Comment: I am just trying to do the first - split polylines that are already in multiple segments into multiple shapefiles.

Comment: Have a look at the feature iterator in the help file. The group by field should be set a field that uniquely identifies the row (usually the Fid) and feed the output into a select tool using inline substitution to create the unique file names.